# Apply different effects to different components within a slide. Swiper | Ionic

Tags: reactjs, ionic-framework, swiper.js, ionic5

What I'm trying to achieve is regular swiping functionality for the top component of the slide, but a fade effect on the bottom component of the slide.

I have an example showing exactly what I'm looking for here using the banking app Monzo:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZtHEk.jpg

I am building it out using Ionic slides so solutions using that would be ideal but using basic javascript Swiper would definitely help me get on the right track.

I have no idea where to start with this problem so any tips would be much appreciated.

Cheers,
Josh

Comment: use (ionSlideWillChange)="slideWillChange($event)" on ion-slides element and inside the function u set ur logic like u can access the next page that will be entered from the $event and then trigger logic to activate  the active ngSwitchCase that contants the slide pages and set active page for example from master_card to visa_card and u assign the effect u need to be trigered from class and examples of animation could be found in this link `https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/slides`

Comment: Hey @mostafa-harb, cheers for the help. Because I'm using Ionic React I don't have access to the ngSwitchCase unfortunately. Regarding the ionSlideWillChange function won't that only trigger after you release touch before you move over to the next slide? I'm kind of confused when it comes to assigning effects not to the slide itself but the nested components within it. I made this super basic example here https://github.com/joshuarichards001/test/blob/master/src/App.tsx How would I go about editing that App file to get myself on the right track?